# SSIS. Как загрузить xlsx с неизвестным названием?

Tags: sql-server, integration-services

Есть экселька, путь известен, а имя нет. Известно что файл всегда будет один. Без циклов можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно предварительно получить имя файла в переменную и добавить его динамически в Excel Connection Manager, если Вы именно его используете.
Имя файла можно узнать, например, через Script Task, или через Foreach Loop Container (хотя это и цикл, но позволяет получить имя файла в директории).

Comment: В целях экономии времени пришлось циклом пробежаться. Все равно спасибо.